# MySqlDataReader: DataTable.Fill(reader) throws ConstraintException

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader, mysql-connector, mysqldatareader

I have two tables `orders` and `orderdetails`

table orders (PK = id, UNIQUE index on orderno)

```
|id|orderno|
| 1|1000   |
| 2|1001   |
```

table orderdetails (PK = id)

```
|id|orderid|item|qty|
| 1|      1|ABC |  3|
| 2|      1|XYZ |  4|
```

Now I want to query the data with:

```
SELECT o.orderno, od.item, od.qty
  FROM orders o
```

INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderno = od.order

which returns:

```
|orderno|item|qty|
|1000   |ABC |  3|
|1000   |XYZ |  4|
```

However If I use the following code to load the result into a DataTable it fails:

```
var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=orders;Uid=root;";
var commandText = "SELECT o.orderno, od.item, od.qty" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "FROM orders o" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderno = od.order";

var reader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, commandText);
var table = new DataTable("OrdersQuery");
table.Fill(reader); // throws ConstraintException
```

The problem is, that

```
table.Constraints[0]
```

is a `UniqueConstraints` on the orderno column. Propably because

```
reader.GetSchemaTable()
```

has a `IsUnique=true` entry for orderno (which is true in the base table, but not true for the join query).

Even worse, that doesn't help either:

```
table.BeginLoadData(); // msdn docs claim that this should disable constraints
table.Load(reader);
table.EndLoadData();
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

StackTrace:

```
System.Data.ConstraintException Was Unhandled.
  Message=Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints()
       bei System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
       bei System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData()
       bei System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
       bei System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
       bei System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
       bei System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
       bei System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured out, that

```
table.Fill(reader)
```

does not create the constraint, if I already added the columns.

So I fixed this by using a nice little extension method:

```
    public static void Load(this DataTable table, IDataReader reader, bool createColumns)
    {

        if (createColumns)
        {
            table.Columns.Clear();
            var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
            foreach (DataRowView row in schemaTable.DefaultView)
            {
                var columnName = (string)row["ColumnName"];
                var type = (Type)row["DataType"];
                table.Columns.Add(columnName, type);
            }
        }

        table.Load(reader);
    }
```

Usage:

```
table.Fill(reader, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing mate! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem but got it fixed by using the workaround from this post: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65065 (at bottom):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cam.no_serie, t.mnt FROM trx t LEFT JOIN camn cam USING(id_camn) ";
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);
    ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
    dataTable.Load(dr);
    dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is simple dirty way how to fix it - surround column in query with unique contraint with concat function:

```
var commandText = "SELECT CONCAT(o.orderno, ''), od.item, od.qty ...";
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error today and want to share.My problem was a column with a LONGTEXT type. If I include LONGTEXT column in my query and  tried to load dataset without specifying column names exception was thrown. Based on SchlaWiener's code I rewrote the code as follows and everything is fine now.

```
MySqlDataReader resultSet = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Columns.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.FieldCount; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(resultSet.GetName(i));
}
dt.Load(resultSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows multiple null values in unique indexes. This causes ConstraintException on fill. How to fix: find this constraint in the 'table.Constraints' list and remove it or just clear all constraints.

Comment: Multiple null values aren't the problem. The `table.Load()` method creates a Contraint on Orderno because the reader.GetSchemaTable() has `IsUnique` = true for the Orderno column, wich is wrong for a Join query.

Comment: I thought about that, too. But if I use the overload that accepts a FillError delegate, it doesn't fire. Can't tell why, because that's what I should expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the queries, when loading the Datatable () with the MYSQL Reader it generated error NON-NULL, UNIQUE or FOREIGN-KEY.

In the end I solved it by changing the MySQL Connector.NET version.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/